# Changing the transparency of a raster layer with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.3, visual-studio, transparency-opacity

I'm trying to do some simple things with the .net framework and ArcObjects, but have little experience with this type of development.  I would like to iterate through the layers in a map document and change the transparency of the raster layers who's names begin with the letter "g".  Here is what I have so far as part of a windows form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
    IMap map = mxdoc.FocusMap;
    for (int i = 0; i < (map.LayerCount - 1); i++)
    {
        ILayer currentLayer = map.get_Layer(i);
        if (currentLayer.Name[0].ToString() == "g")
        {
            //current layer transparency = 50%
        }
    }
}
```

the line that is commented out is where I need help.  I can't seem to find the right code to do what I want within the ILayer class.  Is this not what I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to loop through layers in ArcMap is to use IEnumLayer. You get a reference to that from IMap.Layers.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000482000000

Then check the type and cast each raster layer returned by the enumerator to IRasterLayer.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000p9n000000

And then set the transparency with ILayerEffects.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ILayerEffects_Interface/00120000072m000000/

***EDIT to show example of IEnumLayer:***

```
protected override void OnClick()
{
    IMap pMap = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap;
    ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IUID uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();
    uid.Value = "{D02371C7-35F7-11D2-B1F2-00C04F8EDEFF}";
    IEnumLayer pEnumLayer = pMap.get_Layers(((ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID)(uid)), true);
    pEnumLayer.Reset();
    ILayer pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next();
    do
    {
        MessageBox.Show(pLayer.Name);  //or code that sets layer transparency.
        pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next();
    } while (pLayer != null);
}
```

IEnumLayer is nice because it allows you to choose whether or not to drill down into composite layers (using the second argument in the get_Layers function), and it allows you to restrict which types of layers are returned (first argument in the get_Layers function). The above only returns RasterLayers. An alternative way is to get all the layers (first argument in the get_Layers function to `null`), and then test each layer for its type and do something depending on the type of layer.

GUIDs to be used to restrict layers returned can be found here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000005w000000

Comment: Excellent, this works great.  I didn't use the IEnumLayer but the casting and transparency setting is exactly what I needed.  Could you elaborate on IEnumLayer and possibly give and example of how you would implement it.

Comment: Edited answer with an example of IEnumLayer.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Dan's answer on enumerating layers... with the UID.Value of IRasterLayer ([see example UIDs here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000005w000000)) supplied to the get_layers function you don't need to check later that it is a raster layer you're playing with, however sometimes you need to use the UID for IDataLayer which will return feature layers and raster layers, so to check this use:

```
if (pLayer is IRasterLayer)
```

Another thing you do need to check when working with layers is that the datasource is valid, using `ILayer.Valid` property before trying to adjust any of the settings of the layer (or trying to get a cursor especially):

```
if (pLayer.Valid)
{
    if (pLayer.Name.ToUpper()[1] == 'G')
    {
        IRasterLayer pRasterLayer = (IRasterLayer)pLayer;
        ILayerEffects pLayerEffects = (ILayerEffects)pRasterLayer;
        pLayerEffects.Transparency = 60; // set layer transparency to 60%
    }
}
```

This should interface with Dan's answer to set the transparency of the layer.

Comment: Great, thanks for the extended info. I'm going to try to iterate based on the following: `if ((pLayer.Valid)  && (pLayer.Name[1] == 'g') && (pLayer is IRasterLayer))`

Comment: I don't recommend doing it that way. Check the Valid separately or the pLayer is IRasterLayer could cause an exception.. (pLayer.Name[1] == 'g') && (pLayer is IRasterLayer) can be done together though, saves one level of indent.